# ¿Como introducir - entre caracteres de un cadena en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo la siguiente cadena :

```
var cadena = "Hola que tal estas";
```

Queria saber como se puede mostrar separada por guiones, es decir:

```
var cadena = "H-o-l-a-q-u-e-t-a-l-e-s-t-a-s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede lograr utilizando `String.replace(regex, replacement)`, `Array.split` y `Array.join()`.

Primero tenenos que eliminar los espacios en blanco y para eso utilizamos replace y luego separamos cada caracter con el metodo split() y luego lo juntamos con el metodo join() utilizando el - como separador:

```js
function convertir()
{
  var input = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  console.log(input.replace(/\s/g, '').split('').join('-'));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" />

<button onclick="convertir()">Convertir</button>
```

Comment: Si usas ES6 recomiendo usar Array.from() en lugar de split. No es buena idea para este cometido utilizar split, mira la respuesta de @hakatashi en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript

Comment: @MarcosMartínez Tal cual dice en esa misma respuesta, lo único necesario es utilizar un regex con el modificador `/u`, nada más que eso. O, mucho más sencillo aún `[...input]`.

Answer (score 3):

Una posible forma de lograrlo es:

- Reemplazar espacios mediante [String.replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) ya que no son parte del resultado final
- Obtener un array con todos los caracteres del string mediante [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- Unir los elementos del array de caracteres con el separador `"-"` mediante [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- Retornar el resultado de la operación anterior.

```js
let convertString = (aString) => {
   return Array.from(aString.replace(/\s/g, '')).join("-");
}

const cadena = "Hola que tal estas";
console.log(convertString(cadena));
```

Otra forma es utilizar [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para descartar espacios y [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) para unir con `"-"`

```js
let convertString = (aString) => {
   return Array.from(aString).filter((item)=>{
      return item !== " ";
   }).join("-");
}

const cadena = "Hola que tal estas";
console.log(convertString(cadena));
```

Answer (score 0):

Con un solo replace:

```
cadena = cadena.replace(/(.)(?!$)\s*/ug,'$1-');
```

Answer (score 0):

esto mismo se podría hacer en C?
Estoy intentando lo mismo casi, pero en vez de separarlo con un caracter ,que sea el que la persona digite.. por ejemplo.. puede ser un punto, una coma, etc.

Comment: Hola, Sammu. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Este es el apartado que se usa para dar una respuesta a la pregunta del usuario (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Más adelante, en cuanto alcances más puntuación, tendrás la oportunidad de usar el apartado de comentarios para poder dejar este tipo de cuestiones. Saludos.